# How to specify lower bound as 0 on Bayesian priors

Tags: bayesian, rstanarm

I am using rstanarm and want to create priors that are bound to be positive, so lower>0. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not currently possible with the rstanarm package. It is possible if you use the brms package or write your own Stan code.